# "method 'add' of object 'SmartArtNodes' failed"

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have the follow code that is running in an Excel and it's calling a PowerPoint slide. I am setting a text to each existing node of the SmartArt and it's working. However, I am getting error when I use AddNode method (`oSmartArt.AllNodes.Add.AddNode`). What am I doing wrong?

```
Set oSmartArt = d_ppt_output.Slides(SLIDE_SMART).Shapes("MyList").SmartArt

x = 1
While Cells(x, 1).Text <> ""
    If x > oSmartArt.Nodes.Count Then
        oSmartArt.AllNodes.Add.AddNode ''''' ERROR IS HERE!
    End If

    oSmartArt.AllNodes(x).Shapes.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 2).Text
    x = x + 1
Wend
```

I also replaced `oSmartArt.AllNodes.Add.AddNode` by `oSmartArt.Nodes.Add.AddNode` but I get the same problem.

The error is:
***-2147467259 (80004005)***
***Method 'add' of object 'SmartArtNodes' failed***

The whole code can by found here - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_O79iiG7hbBjMHMSH6kZGkWmjN1WGorR?usp=sharing

Comment: I found the description of this error (-2147467259 80004005) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-time-error-2147467259-80004005 but I don't understand what to do...

Answer (score 0):

As posted, your code doesn't run. You can't reference a slide with a name that's not in quotes. I created a super-simple version in PowerPoint that starts with a 5-member SmartArt. This is running without an error. It adds a new node and fills in the text as expected:

```
Sub Test()
    Set oSmartArt = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).SmartArt
    oSmartArt.AllNodes.Add.AddNode
    oSmartArt.AllNodes(6).Shapes.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Wha?"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi John! Yes, it's not all the code here, but I will post the whole files. So, If I code this inside of PowerPoint, it works, however, I am coding it in Excel VBA which calls a PPT Presentation. I am able to change the texts of SmartArt but I get error if I try to Add. I will post the hole files here in some minutes

Comment: I shared on the link the files. The code is in Excel file, it uses the PPT Template to build the presentation. In the code, there are two places that you need to change the path, I place a comment where to change, then it will run and the error will appear. Other thing is that you have to change in the References of VBA to point to your version of PowerPoint - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_O79iiG7hbBjMHMSH6kZGkWmjN1WGorR?usp=sharing

Comment: Just to complement, you need to change the path in the Sub called "Generate" (poiting the path to the templete and an output directory). The error happen in the Sub "SB_Gera_Slide_SmartArt"